# I can't participate in chat

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, chat

I recently joined security stack exchange, having been a member of other SE sites.

I chatted in the DMZ room yesterday, and all went fine, but now I can't chat in "chat.stackexchange.com" and I get a message stating that my parent account site is suspended"

I recently changed my parent site to "`security.stackexchange.com`" and my account is not suspended here.

Why can't I chat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a ban on SuperUser and that has carried over to your chat account. I'm looking into the details, but the best thing possible would be to straighten the issue out with the mods over there who issued a ban.

> This user is suspended on the parent site and cannot chat for 354 days.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/47069/vignesh

Comment: i changed parent site to security.stackexchange.com,and i cant ask there in meta since my account is suspended,i cant reply to the moderator too

Comment: @vignesh Your chat account has been cleared of the suspension.